# Scala Converting multiline string to BigInt

Tags: string, scala, type-conversion, bigint

I'm trying to parse 100 50-digit numbers from string with below piece of code:

```
val input = """37107287533902102798797998220837590246510135740250
          |46376937677490009712648124896970078050417018260538
          |74324986199524741059474233309513058123726617309629""".stripMargin
val list = input.split("""\n""").map(BigInt(_))
```

but I'm ending with "java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)". I don't have any idea why this does not work, since when string is splited, each element of list is of type String. Any help would be much appreciated.

Best regards

Comment: I tried your code and there was no errors (scala 2.10.0). Are you sure you provided correct code piece?

Comment: [Here is the online results](http://www.scalakata.com/51b9e3b3e4b0ea2d637b8f3b) (hit green button on top right corner)

Comment: You might want to trim the strings as trailing spaces will break BigInt.

Comment: Can you put the entire stack trace into your post?  The message from the Exception indicates what the string was that caused the failure, but I don't see that in what you posted.  That might be the clue to seeing why you are getting this exception and the rest of us are not.

Comment: Do you pronounce it skaLAkata? Anyway, http://www.scalakata.com/51ba2dd0e4b0ea2d637b8fa3 to imagine a different EOL. Thx for the linx.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you're on Windows, where the EOL is \r\n.

You've got to strip that, too.

Here, I rebooted into Windows to demo...

```
apm@halyard ~/tmp
$ vi bigbomb.scala

apm@halyard ~/tmp
$ skalac bigbomb.scala ; skala bigbomb.Test
"ava.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "35740250
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
```

Note that in cygwin, I have to `:se fileformat=dos` in vi to use the \r\n line endings.

Here is an example where the unacknowledged impedance mismatch between the source EOL and the runtime EOL bugged me:

[some dumb code](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/master/src/compiler/scala/tools/util/PathResolver.scala#L26)

You want to use `s.lines.mkString` to strip it out.