# Multi-line string literals behave sane only in REPL and Worksheet

Tags: string, scala, line-breaks, multiline, string-literals

REPL:

```
scala> val a = "hello\nworld"
a: String = 
hello
world

scala> val b = """hello
     | world"""
b: String = 
hello
world

scala> a == b
res0: Boolean = true
```

Worksheet:

```
val a = "hello\nworld"                        //> a  : String = hello
                                              //| world

val b = """hello
world"""                                      //> b  : String = hello
                                              //| world

a == b                                        //> res0: Boolean = true
```

Normal Scala code:

```
val a = "hello\nworld"

val b = """hello
world"""

println(a)
println(b)
println(a == b)
```

Output:

```
hello
world
hello
world
false
```

Why does the comparison yield true in the REPL and in the Worksheet, but false in normal Scala code?

---

Interesting, `b` appears to be one char longer than `a`, so I printed the Unicode values:

```
println(a.map(_.toInt))
println(b.map(_.toInt))
```

Output:

```
Vector(104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 10, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100)
Vector(104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 13, 10, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100)
```

Does that mean multi-line string literals have platform-dependent values? I use Eclipse on Windows.

Comment: You must have a white space in your IDE document. Have you checked that both report length 11? You could also check with `a.getBytes` if there is a discrepancy.

Comment: Second time this week. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17090537/scala-converting-multiline-string-to-bigint

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess it's because of the [source file encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline).

Try to check `a.toList.length` and `b.toList.length`. It seems `b == "hello\r\nworld"`.

Multi-line string literal value depends not on the platform, but on the encoding of the source file. Actually you'll get exactly what you have in the source file between `"""`. If there is `\r\n` you'll get it in your `String`.